# Deep copy of dictionary created with comprehension not working

Tags: python, deep-copy, dictionary-comprehension

Could you please help me understand why does `deepcopy` not work for all the elements in the dictionary from the example below?

```
import copy
a = [{'id':1, 'list':[1,2,3], 'num':3}, {'id':2,' list':[4,5,6], 'num':65}]
b = {i['id']:copy.deepcopy(i) for i in a}

In [1]: print(id(a) == id(b))                                                                                                                      
Out[1]: False

In [2]: print(id(a[0]) == id(b[1]))                                                                                                                   
Out[2]: False

In [3]: print(id(a[0]['list']) == id(b[1]['list']))                                                                                                                   
Out[3]: False

In [4]: print(id(a[0]['num']) == id(b[1]['num']))                                                                                                        
Out[4]: True
```

In particular, the values associated to the `'num'` key are the same while those for the `'list'` key seem to have been copied successfully with `deepcopy`. I'm guessing it has to do with the data type of the value being stored, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: That is normal. The "num" keys are immutable integer objects. Some of them (from -100 to 256 or so) are precreated on startup and always reused.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the dict comprehension but, as you suggested, with the data type:

```
>>> import copy
>>> x = 1
>>> copy.deepcopy(x) is x
True
>>> x = [1]
>>> copy.deepcopy(x) is x
False
```

The distinction made by @mengban is correct: you have mutable and immutable objects (that depends on the type of the object). Typical examples of immutable objects are: integers (`0`, `1`, `2`...), floats (`3.14159`), but also strings (`"foo"`) and tuples (`(1, 3)`). Typical examples of mutable objects are: lists (`[1, 2, 3]`) or dictionaries (`{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`).

Basically, the `deepcopy` of an immutable object returns the object itself: no actual copy is performed (there's a little trick with tuples: I'll explain it later):

```
>>> x = "foo"
>>> copy.deepcopy(x) is x
True
>>> x = (1, 2)
>>> copy.deepcopy(x) is x
True
```

And `deepcopy` of mutable objects creates a new instance of the object having the same elements.

This the right behavior because when you have acquired a deep copy `o2` of an object `o`, the contract is that this is *your* copy. No operation performed on `o` should be able to modify `o2`. If `o` is immutable, this is guaranteed for free. But if `o` is mutable, then you need to create a new instance, having the same content (this implies a recursive deep copy).

Now what's the matter with tuples?

```
>>> o = ([1], [2])
>>> copy.deepcopy(o) is o
False
```

Even if the tuple itself is immutable, maybe one of its elements could be mutable. If I give you a reference `o2` to the value of `o` (ie `o2 = o`), you can write `o2[0].append(10)` and my object `o` is modified. Hence the `deepcopy` function looks for mutable objects in the tuple, and decides whether an actual copy is necessary or not.

---

Bonus: have a look at the [`deepcopy` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/copy.py#L180). The `_deepcopy_dispatch` maps types to the actual copier:

```
_deepcopy_dispatch = d = {}

...
d[int] = _deepcopy_atomic
d[float] = _deepcopy_atomic
d[bool] = _deepcopy_atomic
...
d[str] = _deepcopy_atomic
...
d[list] = _deepcopy_list
...
d[tuple] = _deepcopy_tuple
...
d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict
...
```

While `_deepcopy_atomic` simply returns the value, `_deepcopy_list`, `_deepcopy_tuple`, `_deepcopy_dict`... perform usually an in-depth copy.

You can check the [`_deepcopy_tuple` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/copy.py#L219) to understand the process. Basically, deep copy every element until an actual copy is made. If a copy was made, create a new tuple of deep copies. Else return the initial tuple.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a reference in your dictionary in your new dictionary you can do the following:

```
new_dictionary = json.loads(json.dumps(old_dictionary))
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a big difference between mutable and immutable types in python.
In general, variable types in Python include lists, dictionaries, and collections. Immutable types include strings, int, float, and tuples.
Re-assigning a variable of an immutable type is actually re-creating an object of an immutable type and re-pointing the original variable to the newly created object (a new memory address is opened up), if no other variables refer to the original object (That is, the reference count is 0), the original object will be recycled.

Comment: "Re-assigning a variable of an immutable type is actually re-creating an object of an immutable type and re-pointing the original variable to the newly created object" this is absolutely incorrect. The semantics of assignment are always the same, regardless of type. Re-assignment **never** creates a new object. It just changes what a name is referring to

Comment: Also, *variables don't have types*